# while-loop doesn't seem to remember variable update - no piping involved

Tags: bash, test, variable-substitution

I am running LMDE 2 ( 'Betsy') with the standard Mate desktop and I have the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# This script starts a specified terminal-binary in "Always on Top"-mode
# The assumption is, that 'wmctrl -l' sorts windows with the 
# in such a way, that the more recently a window has been created, 
# the lower it will be on the list ( compared to windows with the 
# same title).
#
# This is my assumption based on a short observation. The window 
# ids are probably given out in ascending hex numbers
# 
# Note: Using the pid will not help, since all terminals seem to
# be having the same pid
term_title_def='Terminal'
term_title='Terminal_top'
term_cmd="mate-terminal --title=$term_title"

# start terminal, wait for window  to appear and get id of most recently created window
# NOTE: a possible wrap-around of window ids has not been considered here!
eval $term_cmd
win_id=''
while [[ -z $win_id ]]; do
    win_id=$(wmctrl -l | grep "[[:blank:]]$term_title\$" | tail -n 1 | awk '{ print $1 }')
done

# DEBUG
touch /tmp/$win_id

# rename, set as "Always on top"
wmctrl -ir $win_id -T "$term_title_def"
wmctrl -ir $win_id -b add,above
wmctrl -ia $win_id
```

Somehow, the script never exits the while loop ( checked that with `ps aufx`) on first running it from a MATE-panel link after reboot.
The subsequent calls work as expected, that is the link does what I want it to ( see script comments above).

So, somehow, right after starting up MATE, `win_id` isn't expanded correctly in `while`-test, I suppose (?). Or something like that.

Why is that?
I will now try something like `while true; do stuff; break; done` instead and hope it'll work...

UPDATE:
Substituting the `while`-loop above with the following

```
while true; do
    win_id=$(wmctrl -l | grep "[[:blank:]]$term_title\$" | tail -n 1 | awk '{ print $1 }')
    [[ $win_id ]] && break
done
```

didn't change anything. The script is still stuck in an infinite loop...

Comment: Maybe the assignment in `while` loop is culprit, `win_id` wasn't updated.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? What could be wrong with the assignment? Also, then why does the script work on subsequent calls?

Comment: Maybe `wmctrl -l | grep "[[:blank:]]$term_title\$" | tail -n 1 | awk '{ print $1 }'` won't return anything at the first time, try running it before assignment.

Comment: But then, don't you think that the script should never work - I have a hard time imagining that only on the first call of the script, the first call of that command **never** returns anything ( I might still try what you've suggested later on, however I'd still like to know the reason for that weird behavior then)? But it does on the second call, for example...

Comment: Try running the script with `set -x` before while loop. If possible, post the output here

Comment: `wmctrl -l` return list of windows managed by window manager. There can be no windows managed at the first time, maybe.

Comment: @SHW not really possible, since it is run from the MATE-panel as a link? Echoing also seemed to cause problems at a point,maybe because if you run links from the panel, printing to `stdout` is problematic.

Comment: @cuonglm no windows at what first time? The first loop is running infinitely, even after I run the script a second time.

Comment: How are you starting the script? Tried logging its stderr stream?

Comment: I don't see how it even enters the `while` loop. When you run `eval $term_cmd` (no need for eval, by the way, just `$term_cmd` would do), a terminal is launched and then the script waits for it to exit. Did you forget to add a `&`?

Comment: I haven't figured out what your script is doing exactly, but if the loop doesn't exit, it's obvious that it's because `win_id` is being set to an empty string inside the loop. The variable update *is* remembered, but if you never put a non-empty value, you'll never get a non-empty value back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see how this could work. When you run

```
eval $term_cmd
```

you will open a terminal window and the script won't do anything else until you close it. What you need is:

```
$term_cmd &
```

Run it in the background (and don't use `eval`, it's not needed). Then, you also don't need to select the last line of `wmctrl`'s output., You are setting the terminal title, so set it to something unique and `grep` that:

```
#!/bin/bash
# This script starts a specified terminal-binary in "Always on Top"-mode
# The assumption is, that 'wmctrl -l' sorts windows with the 
# in such a way, that the more recently a window has been created, 
# the lower it will be on the list ( compared to windows with the 
# same title).
#
# This is my assumption based on a short observation. The window 
# ids are probably given out in ascending hex numbers
# 
# Note: Using the pid will not help, since all terminals seem to
# be having the same pid
term_title_def='Terminal'
term_title="Terminal_top_$$" ## Use the script's PID for a unique title
term_cmd="mate-terminal --title=$term_title"

## Start terminal. No need to wait, the loop will run until
## the terminal has been opened
$term_cmd &

win_id=''

while [[ -z "$win_id" ]]; do
    ## No need for '[[:blank:]]' and \$, you are using a unique title,
    ## keep the regex general. 
    win_id=$(wmctrl -l | grep "$term_title" | awk '{ print $1 }')
done
# DEBUG
touch /tmp/$win_id

# rename, set as "Always on top"
wmctrl -ir $win_id -T "$term_title_def"
wmctrl -ir $win_id -b add,above
wmctrl -ia $win_id
```

Comment: "$term_cmd" & does **not** work. I've tried that before. The bash will try to interpret the whole string as a single command and fail.
Even omitting the double quotes did not yield anything better than what I've had so far... and are you sure about the `$$`-part? I guess you forgot there were single quotes around the assignment string

Comment: oh I oversaw you changed it to double quotes, never mind :)
I think this answer is ready to be approved once my edits are accepted

Comment: @polynomial_donut what edits? I haven't seen any suggested edits on this answer. What do you need?

Comment: Quoting my own former comment: 
"$term_cmd" & does not work. The edit has been approved of already.

Comment: @polynomial_donut it does here. The quotes might make a difference (not at my pc now, so I can't check, I didn't quote it in my test) but eval is not needed. In any case, the main point is that you need to run the terminal in the background.

Comment: the `eval` originally was in order to be able to do 
`"$term_cmd"` without bash trying to interpret the complete expanded string `term_cmd` as a single command and thus failing ( happened to me on two different systems).
Maybe `eval "$term_cmd &"` might also work and combine the advantage of being able to double-quote `term_cmd` and evaluate it without ruining the command?

Comment: @polynomial_donut since you're only using it once, I don't understand why you're using a variable at all? Why not just run `mate-terminal --title=$term_title` directly? Why bother saving it in a variable and creating all these issues in the first place?

Comment: because of reusability of the script on other systems with different terminals etc..

Answer (score -2):

The while loop is executed in a subshell, so any modification made to the variable in the subshell is not reported into the father shell : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16854280/modifying-variable-inside-while-loop-is-not-remembered

For the second issue on my side i have :

```
$ while true; do toto=plop; echo $toto; [[ $toto ]] && break ; done 
plop
```

So i do think you have a real problem with the definition of `$win_id` inside the loop.

Comment: That's the pipe cause the subshell, not `while` loop. It's not the same in this question.

Comment: @cuonglm is right, you should also read my question completely. If the problem was a subshell, then with the loop-variant I have posted, the script should work, shouldn't it...?

Comment: Yeah sorry for the first explanation, the pipe creates the subshell not the while loop. I see an echo $win_id, what does it display inside the infinite loop ?